# it is posibble to block meetings via Android calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

How Can I block meetings via Android calendar and save the result in the database?
I am beginner and can anyone share their knowledge please ?

Comment: I tried with the date picker to change the date..but it was not i wanted I want both date and time so that I can  schedule a meeting [eg 25th July 3-4 PM.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For storing data in the database please go through this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html. For getting date and time you can achieve in the following manner.

```
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFoamat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateandTime = dateFoamat.format(calender.getTime());
    Toast.makeText(this, dateandTime , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

dateandTime String will show you current date and time.

Comment: @Akshay- Is there way a I can display a calendar on the screen with current week highlighted?

Comment: @Srikanth Hey take a look at this post it will help you defiantly http://code.google.com/p/android-calendar-view/